# Как сделать рамку вокруг EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

Как сделать желтую рамку вокруг `EditText`?

И как потом изменить цвет этой рамки? :)

Вот эта желтая рамка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что Вы подразумеваете под рамкой? >`В Eclipse у меня она появлялась автоматически`-среда разработки не влияет на внешний вид приложения, разница может быть из за разных таргетовых версий `Android API`

Comment: @ermak0ff, видимо стиль был другой. Фото рамки добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

как я понял Вам нужно это

[image: Это EditText]

Создаем файл **EditTextStyle.xml** в папке **drawable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:thickness="0dp"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
         android:color="#4799E8"/>
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <gradient
   android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
   android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:type="linear"
   android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Добавляем атрибут в EditText `android:background="@drawable/EditTextStyle"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearchEditText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Search text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/EditTextStyle"/>
```

должно помоч ([на английском](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/845894/How-to-make-EditText-With-Border-and-Gradient-Back))

**UPD:**

> И как потом изменить цвет этой рамки? :)

меняете эти строки

```
...
<stroke android:width="3dp"
         android:color="#4799E8"/>
...
   android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
   android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
...
```

**UPD 2:**

> Как увеличить отступ синей рамки от текста? Он прилегает в плотную

для этого нужно добавить `padding` на `EditText`

```
<EditText 
android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
android:paddingRight="10dp" 
android:paddingTop="10dp" 
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
...
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Заработало! Но есть еще вопрос: а как увеличить отступ синей рамки от текста? Он прилегает в плотную.

Comment: `android:padding="8dp"`

Comment: В ``EditText`` или ``shape``?

Comment: `<EditText
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"`

Comment: Благодарю :))).

Comment: Спасибо, удачи.!!