# EditText с цветным оформлением границ

Tags: android

Как сделать кастомный EditText как на скриншоте. Изначально он выглядит так как поле серого цвета. Но когда нажимаешь на него, чтобы ввести текст, он становится таким как фиолетовый. Как такой же сделать? Может есть готовое решение или это стандартный EditText?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459192/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-edittext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К элементу TextInputLayout установите следующий стиль:

`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`

и в этот же элемент добавьте EditText

**Пример:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Способ приготовления"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

**Результат:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цвет устанавливается из файла *color.xml* параметр *colorAccent*

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.